# PostgreSQL "IF" issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table named `Savannah` and I have 2 columns there: `animals` and `weight`.

In `SELECT` string (without `WHERE` operators etc) I need (with IF operator) show "grow history" for animals named "lion".

It's like: `if animals = 'lion', show 'weight'`

How can I do this?

This full query:

```
SELECT 
    f.id, f.date, f.login, f.fever_id, sum(p.source),
    CASE animals WHEN 'lion' THEN weight END 
FROM 
    fb_prefer f
LEFT JOIN
    region r ON f.region_id = r.id 
LEFT JOIN
    patrools p ON f.region_id = p.region_id
LEFT JOIN
    savannah_stats z ON f.region_id = z.region_id
WHERE 
    f.source > '0'
GROUP BY 
    f.id, f.fever_id
```

Comment: Note: there is no `IF` *operator* in SQL. But: in your case, maybe `CASE` might be usable.

Comment: Please read this part of the manual for `CASE WHEN ...` expression: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: But: what do you want to "show" if the animal is *not* a 'lion' ?

Comment: could you please explain in plain English what is the query supposed to return?

Comment: In part where i have troubles: weight stat (unique per every animal) per some animals.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _formatted_ text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  animals, CASE animals WHEN 'lion' THEN weight END AS "Grow History"
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: Thx! But need it in form like this: 
SELECT if((animals='lions',)weight) as Grow History
FROM mytable

Comment: @RuslanPodgorny: there is no `if` in SQL. This answer will return exactly what you want. Try it.

Comment: But how code will be looking, if i want know not only 'lion' but some others animals?

Comment: @RuslanPodgorny: `CASE WHEN animals IN ('lion', 'zebra') THEN weight END`

Comment: I mean "as Weight_lion, Weight_zebra" etc?

Comment: @RuslanPodgorny: then you have to re-write the query. SQL queries return fixed number of columns.

Comment: Please, and how will it look?

Comment: @RuslanPodgorny: `CASE animals WHEN 'lion' THEN weight END, CASE animals WHEN 'zebra' THEN weight END`

Comment: @RuslanPodgorny: you can't trick a query into returning different number of columns in each record, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: So i've got this error:
ERROR:  column "z.animals" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @RuslanPodgorny: please post your table layout, your query and some sample data.

Comment: This full qeury:
`SELECT f.id, f.date, f.login, f.fever_id, sum(p.source),
CASE animals WHEN 'lion' THEN weight END 
FROM fb_prefer f
Left join region r
on f.region_id=r.id 
Left Join patrools p
On f.region_id=p.region_id
Left Join savannah_stats z
on f.region_id=z.region_id
WHERE f.source>'0'
Group by f.id, f.fever_id`

Comment: @RuslanPodgorny: please update your post, not the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use Case expressions to achieve this. 
Syntax is something like this: 
    SELECT CASE animals WHEN 'lion' THEN weight
           END
    FROM Savannah;

You can also write multiple case expressions or multiple WHEN, THEN expressions.

Comment: Thx! But need it in form like this: 
SELECT if((animals='lions',)weight) as Grow History FROM mytable